# Bloqueo de frame

Tags: angular, angular7, iis

tengo un proyecto en Angular 7 desplegado sobre iis, y necesito bloquear la conexión a toda página que llame el proyecto desde un frame o iframe, de modo que solo pueda ser llamado directo desde el navegador. les agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

después de tanto buscar, encontre que basta con crear en IIS la Cabecera HTTP Response X-Frame-Options con valor "SAMEORIGIN"